# Apply the same editing to all tables in a folder

Tags: r

I have 200 dataframes with names say: data1, data2 data3,...these dataframe have gene mutation values and they are all in the same folder, their format is as follows:

```
chr . Position . ID    . REF . Alts . VarQaul .  Type    . Gene  
  1 . 9765645  .rs234  .  A  .  C   .   71    .missense  . CDK11
  1 . 34587    .rs43456.  C  .  T   .  128    .missense  . TAS1R
--- . -------- .-------. --- . ---- . ------  .--------- . -----
```

and so on, each table with same number of columns but different number of rows

I am wondering if there is a short hand way of taking columns 1 (Chr)and 2 (Position) and concatenate them with a underscore into a new column like so: 1_9765645 then extract that column from all the files in the folder and bind them into a new table with the name of each dataframe file as the column name for the combined column

```
data1   .   data2  .   data3 .    
1_65465 .  1_34568 . 2_56899 . 
2_54456 .  3_4568  . 4_65434
2:76543 .  3_65478 . 5_54323
```

Thank you in advance any help is greatly appreciated

Best regards,
Andres

Comment: You have a `list` of `data.frame`s, but ... you also have files in folders. If you want to work with a list, stay with a list and remove the files/folders references. This question would be improved a lot of you provided literal sample data, perhaps 3 rows from each of 3 frames, and in a `list`. Please also include the expected output from that sample data.

Answer (score 0):

Try the following base R approach

```
#Get complete path of the files
file_names <- list.files("/path/to/folder/", pattern = "^data", full.names = TRUE)

do.call(rbind, lapply(seq_along(file_names), function(x) {
   #Use read.csv or any other way you can read your data 
   df <- read.csv(file_names[x])
   #Concatenate column 1 and column 2 with "_" as separator and assign 
   #column name as name of the file
   setNames(data.frame(paste(df[[1]], df[[2]], sep = "_")), basename(file_names[x]))
}))
```